# Bootcamp Windows 10: Bluetooth works, but mouse not found

Tags: bootcamp, windows, bluetooth, mouse

I'm having some weird issues with getting my bluetooth mouse to work on a Bootcamp Windows 10 installation.

I've verified that bluetooth per se is working by connecting other bluetooth devices (my phone) to the computer. However, my bluetooth mouse (ironically a Windows Bluetooth Design Mouse) won't show up in the bluetooth device scans. It is the same mouse I normally use in OS X on the same computer.

Any idea why I can't connect that particular device in the Bootcamp Windows 10 version? What could I try to make bluetooth recognize the mouse or troubleshoot why it isn't?

So far I've once used the Bootcamp Driver download an made a fresh setup install of Bootcamp.

Edit: In addition to this, I've tested and also another Logitech bluetooth mouse can't be found either via the bluetooth assistant.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this was not an issue with the Bootcamp installation or its drivers. I did not know you had to hold the power botton of the mouse to make it pair. So in order to get it to work, go to Bluetooth, turn Bluetooth on, turn mouse on, hold power button pressed, the mouse will then show up under Bluetooth devices, then pair it.